# Selecting all outlets on xcode ios 8

Tags: ios, xcode

I was just wondering how I can select all outlets on xcode ios 8. Some of my labels are on top of each other, so I cant select them.

Thanks

Comment: There is a small button with an arrow pointing LEFT <|  click on that and it will open a view where you can select the specific items you want.

Comment: An outlet is not a thing (it's just a name). If you want to select labels, ask about that.

Answer (score 2):

Probably the most useful secret trick in Xcode's nib editor is to Shift-Control-click on an interface item in the canvas. This gives a menu where you can select that interface item *or anything behind it*.

Comment: @logixologist Although I think your answer is probably what the OP is looking for; that thing is called the Document Outline, by the way, and you can just choose Editor -> Show Document Outline if it is collapsed.

Comment: right.... I couldnt think of what it was called. I actually asked the same question a long time ago and got a "just use Document Outline".... I had to then search on what it was.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you are trying to select some elements but because they are overlapping you can't get to them.

[image]

Click on the box with a line in it as show in the illustration and it will show all your elements and you can select it from their. In previous Xcode versions it was an arrow instead of a line.

Thank you @matt for pointing out, that is called the Document Outline.